# How to style a child element when its parent element is hovered on (js stylesheet)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a js style file with a notification component that has its own class. It contains a viewDot div with its own separate class in the same file that is present when the notification hasn't been clicked on yet. The viewDot div is inside of the div that has the notificationStyle class.

I want to make it so that if I hover over the notification with a cursor, the color of the viewDot also changes. As it is below, the color of the viewDot only changes if I hover directly on the viewDot. Any tips on accomplishing the described behavior are greatly appreciated

```
const styles = theme => ({
    viewDot: {
        backgroundColor: '#00B8C4',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#F9D967',
        }
    },
    notificationStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#52B5C2',
        },
        // want to do something like this, but this is not correct as is
        '&:hover .viewDot': {
            backgroundColor: '#F9D967'
        }
    },
});
```

The variable `styles` is imported from this ComponentStyles.js file to a Component.jsx file for a Component using the file path and the styles are made using `const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);` before the code block for the component. In the code block for the component, I use `const classes = useStyles();` in order to use something like `className={ classes.notificationStyle }` for the elements inside the component.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `'&hover.viewDot` to `'&:hover .viewDot`.

The [`hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) requires a `:` since it is a pseudo-class, and you need a space between the two classnames since you want to specify a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) relation

---

**Update**

Seeing that you use MUI and JSS, the names in theme are not actually converted to class names and that is why `'&:hover .viewDot'` did not work.

The correct syntax to reference another style defined in the same scope is to use [`$ruleName`](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.9.0#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet), so in this case `'&:hover $viewDot'`

Comment: My bad I missed that syntax error, I fixed it however the dot still does not change color if I hover on the notification, still only if I hover directly on the dot. Any thoughts as to what else might be missing from my styling code?

Comment: @Anthony can you please post which js->css system you use ? In other words where is the `styles` variable used so i can check the docs.

Comment: Hi Gabriele, I just edited the question to include those details

Comment: @Anthony added update